"Bi-bumped" ROC curve meaning?
I am exploring some models for the classification of proteins based on their similarity. Briefly, I am testing the classification with a binomial fit and then analyzing the corresponding ROC curve to look for the threshold showing the best combination of sensitivity/specificity. One of my curves is "bi-bumped" (B-shaped? bi-phasic?) and I am wondering what this means:

Can anyone explain the implications (if any) of such shape and point to ways of improving it?
**Edited to add the fit of the binomial distribution with which I obtained the ROC curve. Hope this helps!


I honestly have never seen a ROC curve with that many points shaped that way before :). a ROC that looks like this suggests that low cutoff values or high cutoff values are both good, but having an intermediate cutoff value is not as good. If you want a better answer than that, we probably need to know at least the true class prevalences and the distribution of the predicted probabilities, and likely more info about the model and predictors.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What do the plots of the predicted probabilities look like? Could you please graph those and post the images?
